# What is the meaning of "vote" in the expression "vote of thanks"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to Collins dictionaries "vote of thanks" means:

A vote of thanks is an official speech in which the speaker formally thanks a person for doing something

A vote means a choice of somebody in a poll.
So, which context has it been used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vote of thanks occurs when a group of people, a committee, a Parliament, etc is asked to assent, by voting, to a proposition that the group officially thanks someone. This is usually a formality (that is, everybody votes for the motion).